# Best practices: checking a path with Costmap2DROS

Tags: ros, navigation, collision, costmap-2d, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a populated Costmap2DROS object and a vector of poses which make up the robot's path.  I need to verify that on every pose, the robot is not in collision.

It should be sufficient to check whether the pose lies within the robot's inscribed radius, although if the computational load is light enough I could check the robot's footprint.

What are the best practices for doing this with a Costmap2DROS? I have found that I can make a copy of the underlying costmap, but this seems inefficient.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28001/best-practices:-checking-a-path-with-costmap2dros/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use the `CostmapModel` class in the `base_local_planner` package to allow you to check if a given pose is in collision. You can find documentation on the class [here](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1CostmapModel.html).

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2